# How do you edit all values in a map without knowing the keys?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

***(context)***
I'm doing more Minecraft spigot things, and my plugin idea is that enchantments strengthen over time, exponentially. I have a timer that is in the *onEnable* thing that runs a function every 2 1/2 minutes.
The function currently does:
Get a list of players,
Get inventory of those players,
Get all items of those inventories,
Get the enchantment maps for each of the items.
The problem is, I don't know every enchantment's code name(plus it would be very tedious to list every single one out), therefore I can't test every key(enchant name) to get the values(the enchantment strength). I want to just edit all of the values and set them to *ceil(lvl*1.2)* so I can get the strengthened enchantments to apply to the items, then apply those items to those  inventories, then inventories to players.

***TL;DR***
How to you edit **every** *value* of a map given that you don't know the keys?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Map's [entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) method to iterate through each enchantment/level.

```java
for (Map.Entry<Enchantment, Integer> entry : enchantmentMap.entrySet()) {
    Enchantment enchantment = entry.getKey();
    int level = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Just checked back in, what does the part inside the for() part do? And, I'm supposed to change enchantmentMap into my map, right?